# Windows 8 Indexing

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

When I put folder of word documents into a directory I used to be able to use explorer to search through the document text and it would match words on content inside the word documents.  Recently this funcationality has stopped?  Any ideas on why it would not be working?  I have check the folder properties and it has 'Allow files in this folder to have contents indexed in addition to file properties' checked?

Comment: control panel > indexing options.  Make sure the path is included.  Setting the folder to be searchable, is not the same thing as the indexer knowing how to find it.

Comment: @Tyson I've checked this and the entire \Users folder is checked.  I've verified all the way down to the individual folder as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was Google Drive.  The folders not being indexed were apart of google drive so I just had to add System to the permissions on the folder, NOT the shortcut.  Everything works now.